# WSO2 Identity Server Update Timezone

Tags: timezone, utc, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm looking to update the **timezone** setting on the **/carbon** page for **WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.**

When I log in I'm seeing "**America/New York**" under '**Operating System User**' in the '**Configure**' tab but I need my timezone to be **UTC**

My centos 6.6 server hosting **WSO2 IS 5.0** has a timezone of UTC and I want WSO2 to match it.

How do I go about changing this setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2IS reads the timezone value using `user.timezone`java system property. I guess, your JVM instance has been set to America/New York timezone by default.  Therefore it has been shown in WSO2IS as well.  If you need to change the timezone,  you can pass it as system property when server is starting

> sh wso2server.sh -Duser.timezone=UTC

Also,  you can add this property in to `wso2server.sh` file. Then you do not need to set this property fro every start by manually

Comment: Thank you for the response. Where specifically would I add that property in the wso2server.sh file? Also, what specifically would I add to the file, would it just be:  -Duser.timezone=UTC?

Comment: You can add the -Duser.timezone=UTC inside the in the 
while [ "$status" = "$START_EXIT_STATUS" ] statement of the wso2server.sh file